# Fundamental group of a bucket

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to compute the fundamental group of a bucket.

**Wrong proof:**

> If I retract the bucket onto the disk at the base what I get is a disk
> with a handle attached to it by two points, which in turn is
> homotopically equivalent to a disk with a circle attached to it by
> a point.
>
> Hence since the fundamental group of the disk is trivial and the
> fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z},$ I get that the
> fundamental group of the bucket is $\mathbb{Z}*\text{id}.$

Now, I already know the computation is right but the proof is wrong.

This is because the retraction of the bucket onto the disk cannot be done in this case because the bucket has the handle. The retraction would make us "lose the information about the handle".

But now consider this other cases:

If instead we imagine a "bucket without handle", this time we could retract it onto the disk to obtain that the bucket without handle has trival fundamental group and it would be a sound proof.

In a similar way, if we consider a bucket with a hole at the bottom, that is a cylinder with a handle attached to it, then in this case we can retract the cylinder onto $S^1$ *without* "losing information" about the handle, and we would get a bouquet of two circles which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}.$

So, the question is

> Why the proofs of these two last cases - bucket without handle or cylinder with a handle - are sound while the first one is not correct? What is the difference? Where is the problem in the first proof?

Comment: The first proof is fine. You just need to be a bit careful about how you write down the (deformation) retraction to incorporate the handle.

Comment: I'd retract the handle first.  Bring the two ends of the handle together first, so it's a circle attached to a bucket.  Then proceed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. But then why in the case of the cylinder with the handle this "care" was not necessary? Why putting a disk at the base instead of a circle make things different?

Comment: It doesn't. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @B.Goddard Thank you. But can you help me understand in what way what you suggest makes the retraction easier and gives a better solution?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So the retraction is the same for the cylinder with the handle?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I say this because I was told that the cylinder with the handle and the bucket had to be treated in different ways. So my confusion stems from the fact that I do not see how they are different.

Comment: I don't see why that would be the case. Best to ask whoever told you that for clarification.